# ¿Cómo leer el mensaje XML de un HTTP POST?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

Estoy creando un *API* y no tengo muy claro cómo puedo leer el mensaje *XML* que recibo.

Tengo un *trigger* que una vez está activada manda un mensaje SOAP a la URL donde está alojada mi *API*, que recibe el *HTTP*, pero no sé cómo leer los datos *XML* que incluye el mensaje.

Sé que en *Python* con la librería ***requests*** es muy fácil sacar el *JSON*, pero no sé si funciona para *XML*.

```
from flask import Flask  
from flask import request  
from flask import make_response  
import os  
app = Flask(__name__)  
@app.route('/prueba', methods=['POST','GET'])  
def prueba():  
    # Every message is received here. I will analyze it    
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    email = req ['data']['email']
    print email
    return None
```

Comment: Hola, proporciona un poco de código para darnos una idea de cómo lo estás haciendo

Comment: ¿Eso es todo? En ese código no se ve que estés haciendo lo que describes en la pregunta. Pega el código completo y te ayudo a editar la pregunta

Comment: Alex: dale a [edit] para añadir más contenido. Los comentarios no son buen lugar para entender código.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por qué querrías convertir el contenido del request a XML, si estás tratando de consumir una API, ese no es el camino

Comment: Yo lo que recibo es un mensaje HTTP. ¿como saco el XML de ahi?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido de ese mensaje HTTP?

Comment: La verdad esque tampoco se muy bien que contiene, unicamente se que es un mensaje XML. El caso es que con requests es muy facil sacar la info del HTTP (si es JSON). ¿porque requests no vale para XML? cual es la libreria equivalente?

Comment: No estoy seguro pero me parece que estás confundiendo el `request` de Flask con la librería [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). El método `request.get_json` es un  método de Flask.

Comment: Perdon, tienes razon. ¿Alguna idea de como flask trabaja con XML?

Comment: ¿Creeis que con un request.get_data() funcionará?

Comment: No me queda claro lo que estás haciendo, tal vez debas pegar el código que estás usando para consumir tu API

Comment: Esque realmente eso es todo lo que tengo de codigo... El funcionamiento es el siguiente:  

1º Salta una alerta y envia un mensaje HTTP POST a la URL: www.app.heroku.com/prueba.

2º En esa URL "estoy escuchando" y al recibir un mensaje POST entra en la función Prueba.

3º Ahora tengo que de ese mensaje POST sacar la informacion contenida (Mensaje XML) para mostrarlo por pantalla/logs

He cambiado un par de cosas en el codigo por si ayudan a hacerse una idea.

Comment: En ese caso, tal vez te sirva [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

Comment: Si, el xmltodict me vale para manejar los datos XML pero el problema es como consigo esos datos del HTTP :(. Muchas gracias por la ayuda de todas formas :)